# Why is adBudgetPricing linkedin API returning status 404 with message 'Resource adBudgetPricing does not exist'?

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, linkedin-api

I am new to using linkedin APIs and all I am trying to do is use this API to make a GET request

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adBudgetPricing?account={AccountNumber}
```

however, it keeps returning status 404 with 'Resource adBudgetPricing does not exist'
What could I be doing wrong?

Linking official docs here--
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ad-budget-pricing?tabs=http#find-pricing-insights-by-criteriav2

Comment: I have run into a similar problem. I'm still working with person internally at LinkedIn to figure out what has changed with their API. In their example they have a `q=criteria` and I get permission denied unless I supply `q=criteriaV2`.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this working for myself with the aid of one of LinkedIn's sales engineers. I was also able to replicate your issue while debugging when I left of the required `q` parameter. If you don't set `q=criteriaV2`, then you'll receive a 404.

Make sure that you're sending all of the required parameters in your request:
[image]